# How to Formatting Database Data Using x:Bind in XAML TextBlock element

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winui-3, winui

In WinUi3 for Windows application development
Here, I want the output to be **'Name: John.'**
The 'Name' data (Like John) is obtained from the database and bound using x:Bind.
I desire the output to be in the format '**Name: John.** is there any alternative way to get this format output.

```
<Grid  x:Name="root" >
     <Grid.Resources>
        <local:StringValueConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>


 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.User.Name,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter='Name'}" />
```

Want desired output like "Name : John"
I tried with Converter also but it's not work with x:Bind Windows application.

```
// This is class for Converter
public class StringValueConverter :  IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return $"{parameter} : {value}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It showing error like this
[If we use Converter then this error occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43kaZ.png)

Comment: The code is not enough to reproduce or analyze the problem.  However, why don't you change your ViewModel tor return "Name: John" instead of using a converter?  Would be easier.

Comment: @Nick I am updated my question, added more code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot use a converter in Window, it is a [well-known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4966).

The workaround is to embed your content in a Page and load the page in the main window.  Or, do not use a converter, and implement the data conversion in the view model, as I suggested in the comment.